# How to sum all element values and append that number to the end of the array?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

How can I calculate the sum of all elements in an array, then append that sum as a new element to the original array?

For example, the sum of `[6,7,8]` is `21` so the array should become `[6,7,8,21]`.

Comment: You question is not well crafted.  Have another look.  Shouldn't `15` be `21`?

Comment: sorry for that. edited

Comment: For all questions in the future, please include your best coding attempt in the question before posting.  This shows that you have put some effort into self-solving before asking for help AND this protects the volunteers from being abused a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the returned value from `array_sum()` onto the end of the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lv6p8))

```
$array = [6,7,8];
$array[] = array_sum($array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 6,
  1 => 7,
  2 => 8,
  3 => 21,
)
```

---

If you are expecting `15` by adding the final two elements, then use this:

```
$array = [6,7,8];
$array[] = array_sum(array_slice($array, -2));
var_export($array);
// [6, 7, 8, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to do this, like:

```
<?php
function sumAppend ( &$array)
{
  $result = array_sum ( $array);
  $array[] = $result;
  return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: it only returns the sum of all numbers in the array i want to append the sum of the array on the original array

Comment: @EfrenBontuyan This answer is not fully considered.  It is using `&$array` which means no `return` call is necessary and `sumAppend($array)` is the way to modify the original. Alternatively, remove the `&` and call `return` and declare `$array = sumAppend($array);` There was no explanation as to how to call the custom function.  See here: https://3v4l.org/bS7cl versus https://3v4l.org/a0dGL  (...but as I have shown, this can be done without a custom function.)

Comment: @EfrenBontuyan the code do exactly what you asked. If you ask to add sum of array to the array, the code will be different, but you asked to return the sum AND modify the array to add it.